# Create a view/list of pages made with Panels

Tags: views, panels

I know how to view/list particular content types in a View:

I just need to add a "filter criteria" to the View that will display all node belonging to that type.

cool. but, I can't figure out how to view/list particular pages made with Panels.

Pages made with Panels are not selectable from the "filter criteria" box in the View.

Comment: This module https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager ? FYI Please ask specifically if you need good on to the point answers.

Comment: @Mauro I don't get what you are trying to accomplish. Can you elaborate on 'view/list pages made with Panels in a View'. Also, at what path(s) are these pages?

Answer (score 0):

Try www.yoursite.com/admin/structure/pages

This lists all the system generated & custom panel pages that exist.